# Swift 4: How many times an element from a String array occurs in a String?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, dictionary

Right now I'm making a small project with the Bible showing miscellaneous facts and data, by book.

I have the actual bible verses and chapter in text, decoded from JSON remotely.

The problem is I am trying to add a feature where it shows the most mentioned names by book. I have here a String array of male and female Biblical names.

How can I count the number of times elements from my String array appears in a single String?

And is there a way I can the number of times elements from my String array appears in another String array?

```
let nameString = """
        Abigail
        Ada
        Ahlai
        Angel
        Anna
"""

let names = nameString.components(separatedBy: "\n")

for chapter in genesis!.chapters{
            for verse in chapter.verses{
                //????????????????
            }
        }
```

I am trying to loop thru my JSON object which has dictionaries, etc.

The verse is a dictionary like ["1":"And God said...."]

Is there a way to check how many times any element in names appears in verses.values?

Comment: I would make structs for each element in your data structure: Book, Chapter, Verse, etc. Then you can recursively count the occurrence of each name.

Comment: Edit your question and post your genesis structure. **"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example."** https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `components(separatedBy:)` instance method of String to get an array containing substrings from the receiver that have been divided by a given separator. From the resultant array's count you could get the occurrences of separator in the given string. In your case as you need to get the occurrences of each element in your names array, your code would end up something like the one below.

```
var namesOccurences: [String:Int] = [:]
for chapter in genesis!.chapters{
    for verse in chapter.verses{
        for verse in verses {
            for name in names {
                let occurences = verse.value.components(separatedBy: name).count - 1
                namesOccurences[name] = namesOccurences[name, default: 0] + occurences
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above method will find words that the names are substrings of as well. If you don't want that to be counted, you can split the verse into words and then loop through them to find the occurrences. Sample code would be like the one follows.

```
var namesOccurences: [String:Int] = [:]
for chapter in genesis!.chapters{
    for verse in chapter.verses{
        for verse in verses {
            let words = verse.split(separator: " ")
            for name in names {
                var occurences = 0
                words.forEach { (subString) in
                   if subString.caseInsensitiveCompare(name) == .orderedSame {
                      occurences += 1
                   }
                }
                namesOccurences[name] = namesOccurences[name, default: 0] + occurences
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wouldn't this find words that the names are substrings of as well?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes. It will. I have updated the answer. Have a look.

Comment: What about names that are next to another character like dot, comma or similar? And why a case insensitive comparison, for first names I would expect an exact match only.

Comment: About case sensitive check, it depends. If you are sure that your input will never have different case scenario you could simply replace that with equal check.

Comment: @SubramanianMariappan If you need to count the number of words in a string and deal with punctuation you can use String method `enumerateSubstrings(in: Range)`and pass `.byWords` options